# Lumen - Testing PUT doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, json, laravel, lumen

I created a test like so:

```
$user = factory(Users::class)->create([
            'userID'=>5
        ]);
        $this->actingAs($user)
            ->put('/user/5', [
                'name' => "Bob Smith",
            ])
            ->get('/user/5')
            ->seeJson(['name'=>'Bob Smith']);
```

But when I run it, the test fails because the PUT didn't update the name of the user. How can I get it to update the user please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it in the end. Changed the `put('/user/5', ['name' => "Bob Smith"])` line to `json('put', '/user/5', ['name' => "Bob Smith"])`